# Trouble writing a MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying on and off the last couple days to write a MySQL query that does the following:

For each class that has at least one qualified professor to teach it, list the number of professors qualified to teach the class.

I tried the following query but it didn't give the correct output

```
select Class, Semester, p.EmpId from Qualified q, Teaches T, Professor p where q.EmpId = p.EmpId and T.EmpId = p.EmpId group by p.EmpId;

+-------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+------+-----------------------------------+
| EmpId | ClassId | EmpId | FName   | LName     | Dept | QualClass                         |
+-------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+------+-----------------------------------+
|   101 | BA101   |   101 | Bobby   | Ewing     | BA   | BA101, BA102                      |
|   102 | BA101   |   102 | Red     | Skeleton  | BA   | BA101, BA102                      |
|   101 | BA102   |   101 | Bobby   | Ewing     | BA   | BA101, BA102                      |
|   102 | BA102   |   102 | Red     | Skeleton  | BA   | BA101, BA102                      |
+-------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+------+-----------------------------------+
```

These are the relevant tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Professor
(
    EmpId INTEGER,
    FName VARCHAR(10),
    LName VARCHAR(10),
    Dept VARCHAR(2),
    QualClass VARCHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (EmpId)
);

CREATE TABLE Teaches
(
    Class VARCHAR(5),
    Section INTEGER,
    Semester CHAR(4),
    EmpId INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (EmpId) REFERENCES Professor(EmpId)
);

CREATE TABLE Qualified
(
    EmpId INTEGER,
    ClassId VARCHAR(5)
);
```

Here are some DML Statements

```
INSERT INTO Professor (EmpId, FName, LName, Dept, QualClass) VALUES (101, 'Bobby', 'Ewing', 'BA', 'BA101, BA102');
INSERT INTO Professor (EmpId, FName, LName, Dept, QualClass) VALUES (102, 'Red', 'Skeleton', 'BA', 'BA101, BA102');
INSERT INTO Teaches (Class, Section, Semester, EmpId) VALUES ('BA101', 1, 'FA12', 101);
INSERT INTO Teaches (Class, Section, Semester, EmpId) VALUES ('BA101', 1, 'SP13', 102);
INSERT INTO Teaches (Class, Section, Semester, EmpId) VALUES ('BA101', 1, 'SU13', 101);
INSERT INTO Teaches (Class, Section, Semester, EmpId) VALUES ('BA102', 1, 'FA12', 102);
INSERT INTO Teaches (Class, Section, Semester, EmpId) VALUES ('BA102', 1, 'SP13', 101);
INSERT INTO Teaches (Class, Section, Semester, EmpId) VALUES ('BA102', 1, 'SU13', 102);
INSERT INTO Qualified (ClassId, EmpId) VALUES ('BA101', 101);
INSERT INTO Qualified (ClassId, EmpId) VALUES ('BA101', 102);
INSERT INTO Qualified (ClassId, EmpId) VALUES ('BA102', 101);
INSERT INTO Qualified (ClassId, EmpId) VALUES ('BA102', 102);
```

Comment: Do you have a `Classes` table?

Comment: Your data is not normalized. What is the purpose of `Professor.QualClass` field?

Comment: What is the point of showing us a result set that bears no relationship to the query which supposedly produced it!?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your statement:

> For each class that has at least one qualified professor to teach it, list the number of professors qualified to teach the class.

The following query lists the *number of professors qualified to teach a class*.  And here is an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccfcfb/10/0) to showcase it works:

```
SELECT Q.ClassId, count(Q.EmpId) as "Professor Count"
FROM Qualified Q
GROUP BY ClassId
```

Now if you need to also know *which* professors are qualified, that would be a *different* query.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly. I did add HAVING COUNT(Q.EmpId) >=1 to the end of it though so it only selected those with at least one professor.